# why i can't use javascript function created inside jquery object and how to declare custom function in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
$(function(){
    function valid(){
        if($('input[type=text]').val() =="" && $('input[type=number]').val() =="" && $('input[type=email]').val() =="" && $('input[type=checkbox]').is('checked')==false){
            alert('Please fill every details');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

when i use console.log(valid()); it says valid() is undefined. how to create a function named valid() in jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jQuery ready is a function, adding a new child method we need to call that method inside itself. Like below.

```
$(function(){
    function valid(){
        return "aaa";
    }

    console.log(valid());
});
```

Where the below throws undefined.

```
$(function(){
   function valid(){
      return "aaa";
   }
});
console.log(valid());
```